# Get calender month from config file codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am using codeigniter. I have added my own months data in config file as follows.

```
application/config/config.php
```

in the config file i have data like this

```
$config['months_data'] = array(1=>'January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December');
```

And I have a month name as 1,2,3 in my database. I just want to replace this data into months name.
I don't know how to do this. Please suggest me a logic. Apologies for asking not detailed question.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is probably not the best strategy. How will you retrieve your month numbers from your db ? Will it be a string like `1,2,3` or it will be one row = one number ? You should give us more than that. Your model could be useful.

Comment: Actually i have stored the column as date. I have get the month using month(date) query.

Comment: I guess @fancyPants got faster than me, this actually what I was thinking of.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See this sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE dates
    (`months` int)
;

INSERT INTO dates
    (`months`)
VALUES
    (1),
    (2),
    (3),
    (4),
    (5),
    (6),
    (7)
;
```

You can get what you want by this query:

```
select
date_format(str_to_date(months, '%c'), '%M')
from
dates
```

- see it working live in this [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2ebced/1/0)

Documentation for the functions [str_to_date()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) and [date_format()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format)

You can update your table like this:

```
update my_table
set month_name_column = date_format(str_to_date(month_number_column, '%c'), '%M')
```

Answer (score 1):

You will get all config details using following,

```
echo "<pre>";
$ci =& get_instance();
echo "</pre>";
```

Use $ci for accessing your month...
Hope this helps